# AngularJS UI Typeahead label and value

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am using the typehead directive to autocomplete a list of states.
The list contains a bunch of objects as follows

```
{
  StateId: 0,
  StateCode: "AK",
  StateDesc: "ALASKA"
}
```

The typehead HTML is as follows

```
typeahead="state.StateCode for state in States | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"
```

This works great as is however I'd like to improve it a little bit.
Is it possible to have the autocomplete dropdown to show (and search on) `StateDesc` but once you click on the drop down item the textbox was populated with `StateCode`?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255477/kendo-angular-multiselect-set-selected-values/20742127#20742127), not angular ui but pretty close to what you want, at least you can dig through the directive code and change it as you see fit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The HTML needs to be

`typeahead="state.StateCode as state.StateDesc for state in States | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"`

Thanks to **Pushpak** for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Since the answer from Pushpak is the correct one, you should mark his answer as the correct one, not your own.

Comment: @DiegoVieira it's not correct, it's a step towards what I asked. Look closely at what I asked vs his answer vs the final result.

Comment: How does this relate to ng-model? When I select a value using this technique, the StateCode is bound to the model and thus visible in the input

Comment: @Hazaart which is what I wanted. This thing before `as` in this case `state.StateCode` is your model. If you want your whole state object to be your model then it's `typeahead="state as state.StateDesc for state in States | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"`

Comment: didn't worked for me: `subconta.subconta as subconta.descricao for subconta in appContabil.subcontas | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:23` shows `subconta.subconta` in the input and sets it to the model (I need to show `subconta.descricao` in the input). Note: using this directly in ng-options *does* work

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you are using [angular-ui bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) typeahead, heres a plunkr of how this can be achieved easily.

http://plnkr.co/edit/NpWC6qvrzx7swGRFlpUR?p=preview